# MatTable width extends instead of overflowing when filled with text

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a table with two columns, and within each columns are two editable divs. I want to be able to edit the cells and add text up until the point where the editable div becomes the cells width, and at that point I want the div to then overflow and show ellipsis for the overflown text.

If I add a `max-width` using px to the editable divs I get the behaviour I want but I want to be able to use % instead so that the design remains responsive, so px is out of the question.

As you can see on the stackblitz, if I add to the editable divs and it overflows the other columns of the table are pushed. I want the width of the table to remain fixed and the width of the columns to also be fixed.

I've tried setting a bunch of widths but nothing seems to have an effect at keeping the width of each column fixed.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-5w1cxe?file=src/app/app.component.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html tables have a style property called `table-layout` that is set to 'auto' by default. If you set it to 'fixed' then the table layout will be fixed based on the widths of the first row and won't expand when you type into the editable div. Just add this to you css (probably want to use the class on the table for the selector)

```
table {
   table-layout: fixed;
}
```

This does create another problem though - when the contenteditable div loses focus the scroll position of the text doesn't reset to 0. You can fix this by resetting it when the div is blurred. Something like this

```
    <div class="editable-input" contenteditable (blur)="resetOverflowPosition($event)">
```

Then in the component add the handler

```
  resetOverflowPosition(event) {
    event.target.scrollLeft = 0;
  }
```

Comment: This was the exact issue. I managed to find this outside of SO, but I've marked your answer as correct. Thanks!